# Long Table Cutting off before End in Appendix

Tags: longtable, appendices

My apologies, I posted a few days ago on this topic as a guest but couldn't update the code for the requested information, so here's a repost (with a full `.tex` for a document recreating the error I'm encountering).  I hope that's ok!

In short, I have an appendix in which I've put two long tables so as to not interrupt the flow of my paper.  The issue is that in the appendix the second table will not fully show- just say "(continued)" at the end and then have a blank page.  It does not matter which order I put the tables, and both tables will display just fine if I take them out of the appendix and put them in the text itself.  If anyone has an idea, I would really appreciate it.

Code to follow for document that creates this error:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{aastex61}
\pdfoutput=1 %for arXiv submission
\usepackage{amsmath,amstext}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{apjfonts} 
\usepackage[figure,figure*]{hypcap}
\usepackage{subfigure}

\renewcommand*{\sectionautorefname}{Section} %for \autoref
\renewcommand*{\subsectionautorefname}{Section} %for \autoref

\shorttitle{Radio Observations}
\shortauthors{Author et al.}

\begin{document}

\appendix
\section{Appendix for Obtained Parameters- Torus and Ring Models}

\tablecaption{Observations and parameters for the data sets in this study.  The line between Days 9,568 and 9,756 denotes new data unique to this work.}
\label{tab:observations}
\startlongtable
\begin{deluxetable*}{lcclcc}
\tabletypesize{\small}
\tablehead{
\colhead{Observing Date} & \colhead{Days since} & \colhead{Array} &
\colhead{Center Frequency\tablenotemark{a}} & \colhead{Time on} &
\colhead{Epoch Shown}  \\ \colhead{} & \colhead{Supernova} &
\colhead{Configuration} & \colhead{(MHz)} & \colhead{Source (hr)} &
\colhead{in Figure~\ref{fig:supernova-shots}\tablenotemark{b}}}
\startdata
1992 Jan 14& 1786 & 6B & 8640  & 12 & \nodata \\
1992 Mar 20& 1852 & 6A & 8640  & 10 & \nodata \\
1992 Oct 21& 2067 & 6C & 8640, 8900 & 13 & 1992.9 \\
1993 Jan 4 & 2142 & 6A & 8640, 8900 & 9 & 1992.9 \\
1993 Jan 5 & 2143 & 6A & 8640, 8900 & 6 & 1992.9 \\
1993 Jun 24& 2313 & 6C & 8640, 8900 & 8 & 1993.6 \\
1993 Jul 1 & 2320 & 6C & 8640, 8900 & 10 & 1993.6 \\
1993 Oct 15& 2426 & 6A & 8640, 9024 & 17 & 1993.6 \\
1994 Feb 16& 2550 & 6B & 8640, 9024 & 9 & 1994.4 \\
1994 Jun 27-28& 2681 & 6C & 8640, 9024 & 21 & 1994.4 \\
1994 Jul 1 & 2685 & 6A & 8640, 9024 & 10 & 1994.4 \\
1995 Jul 24& 3073 & 6C & 8640, 9024 & 12 & 1995.7 \\
1995 Aug 29& 3109 & 6D & 8896, 9152 & 7 & 1995.7 \\
1995 Nov 6 & 3178 & 6A & 8640, 9024 & 9 & 1995.7 \\
1996 Jul 21& 3436 & 6C & 8640, 9024 & 14 & 1996.7 \\
1996 Sep 8 & 3485 & 6B & 8640, 9024 & 13 & 1996.7 \\
1996 Oct 5 & 3512 & 6A & 8896, 9152 & 8  & 1996.7 \\
1997 Nov 11& 3914 & 6C & 8512, 8896 & 7  & 1998.0 \\
1998 Feb 18& 4013 & 6A & 8896, 9152 & 10 & 1998.0  \\
1998 Feb 21& 4016 & 6B & 8512, 9024 & 7  & 1998.0 \\
1998 Sep 13& 4220 & 6A & 8896, 9152 & 12 & 1998.9  \\
1998 Oct 31& 4268 & 6D & 8502, 9024 & 11 & 1998.9  \\
1999 Feb 12& 4372 & 6C & 8512, 8896 & 10 & 1999.7 \\
1999 Sep 5 & 4577 & 6D & 8768, 9152 & 11 & 1999.7 \\
1999 Sep 12& 4584 & 6A & 8512, 8896 & 14 & 1999.7 \\
2000 Sep 28& 4966 & 6A & 8512, 8896 & 10 & 2000.9 \\
2000 Nov 12& 5011 & 6C & 8512, 8896 & 11 & 2000.9 \\
2001 Nov 23& 5387 & 6D & 8768, 9152 & 8 & 2001.9 \\
2002 Nov 19& 5748 & 6A & 8512, 8896 & 8 & 2003.0 \\
2003 Jan 20& 5810 & 6B & 8512, 9024 & 9 & 2003.0 \\
2003 Aug 1 & 6003 & 6D & 8768, 9152 & 10 & 2003.6 \\
2003 Dec 5 & 6129 & 6A & 8512, 8896 & 9 & 2004.0 \\
2004 Jan 15& 6170 & 6A & 8512, 8896 & 9 & 2004.0 \\
2004 May 7 & 6283 & 6C & 8512, 8896 & 9 & 2004.4 \\
2005 Mar 25& 6605 & 6A & 8512, 8896 & 9 & 2005.2 \\
2005 Jun 21& 6693 & 6B & 8512, 8896 & 9 & 2005.5 \\
2006 Mar 28& 6973 & 6C & 8512, 8896 & 9 & 2006.2 \\
2006 Jul 18& 7085 & 6A & 8512, 8896 & 9 & 2006.5 \\
2006 Dec 8 & 7228 & 6B & 8512, 9024 & 8 & 2006.9 \\
2008 Jan 4 & 7620 & 6A & 8512, 9024 & 11 & 2008.0 \\ 
2008 Apr 23& 7730 & 6A & 8512, 8896 & 11 & 2008.3 \\
2008 Oct 11& 7901 & 6A & 8512, 8896 & 11 & 2008.8 \\
2009 Jun 6 & 8139 & 6A & 9000  & 11 &     2009.4 \\
2010 Jan 23& 8370 & 6A & 9000  & 11 &     2010.1 \\
2010 Apr 11& 8448 & 6A & 9000  & 11 &     2010.3 \\
2011 Jan 25& 8737 & 6A & 9000  & 11 &     2011.1 \\
2011 Apr 22& 8824 & 6A & 9000  & 11 &     2011.3 \\
2012 Jan 12& 9089 & 6A & 9000  & 11 &     2012.0 \\
2012 Jun 5 & 9233 & 6D & 9000  & 11 &     2012.4 \\
2012 Sep 1 & 9321 & 6A & 9000  & 10 &     2012.7 \\
2013 Mar 7 & 9509 & 6A & 90006  & 11 &     2013.2 \\
2013 May 5 & 9568 & 6C & 9000  & 11 &     2013.3 \\
\hline
2013 July 18 & 9642 & 6A & 8512, 8896 & 10 & 2013.5 \\ %18.45
2013 Nov 09 & 9756 & 6A & 8512, 8896 & 9 & 2013.9 \\ %17.09
2014 Apr 16 & 9915 & 6A & 8512, 8896 & 8 & 2014.3 \\ %15.74
2016 Mar 03 & 10601 & 6B & 8512, 8896 & 8 & 2016.2 \\ %15.55
2017 February 7 & 10942 & 6D & 8512, 8896 & 9 & 2017.2 \\ %15.84
\enddata
\tablenotetext{a}{Since the CABB upgrade in mid-2009, data have been recorded
over a 2-GHz bandwidth. However, in this analysis we used two 104-MHz subbands
with center frequencies of 8.512\,GHz and 8.896\,GHz, for a consistency with
the bandwidth of pre-CABB data.}
\tablenotetext{b}{Some early datasets have been averaged together to generate the
corresponding images in Figure~\ref{fig:supernova-shots} for the listed epoch.}
\end{deluxetable*}

\startlongtable
\begin{deluxetable*}{lccccccr}
\tablecaption{Best-fit Parameters for the Torus Model with Statistical
Uncertainties at 68\% Confidence Level\label{table:torus}}
\tablewidth{\textwidth}
\tabletypesize{\small}
\tablehead{
\colhead{Day}&\colhead{Flux (mJy)}&\colhead{Radius (\arcsec)}
&\colhead{Half-opening}&\colhead{Thickness}&\colhead{Asymmetry}&\colhead{$\phi$ (\arcdeg)}&\colhead{$\chi^2_\nu$/dof\tablenotemark{a}}\\
&&&Angle (\arcdeg)&\colhead{(\%)}&\colhead{(\%)}}
\startdata
1786& $4.2\pm0.2$ & $0.60\pm0.10$ & $84^{+6}_{-20} $ & $150\pm50$ & $70\pm30$ & $187\pm16$ &1.8/2107\\
1852& $4.0\pm0.3$ & $0.62\pm0.05$ & $80\pm10$ & $100\pm50$ & $100_{-60} $ & $180^{+10}_{-30}$ &3.7/1642\\
2067& $5.73\pm0.12$ & $0.62\pm0.05$ & $33\pm4$ & $175\pm25$ & $81\pm7$ & $121\pm6$ &4.3/3602\\
2142& $5.32\pm0.14$ & $0.65\pm0.02$ & $44\pm2$ & $172\pm10$ & $96\pm3$ & $114\pm7$ &17/2702\\
2143& $5.7\pm0.2$ & $0.64\pm0.01$ & $0^{+12} $ &$0^{+20} $ & $40\pm8$ & $108\pm6$ &16/1392\\
2313& $6.73\pm0.11$ & $0.63\pm0.01$ & $34\pm7$ & $0^{+20} $ & $40\pm5$ & $94\pm14$ &3.6/2902\\
2320& $7.04\pm0.13$ & $0.67\pm0.02$ & $37\pm7$ & $44^{+15}_{-20} $ & $38\pm5$ & $95\pm13$ &4.5/2962\\
2426& $6.65\pm0.10$ & $0.69\pm0.01$ & $55\pm4$ & $33^{+10}_{-16} $ & $42\pm5$ & $85\pm12$ &5.2/4372\\
2550& $6.63\pm0.15$ & $0.64\pm0.04$ & $26\pm5$ & $175\pm20$ & $80\pm6$ & $108\pm5$ &7.5/2992\\
2681& $8.41\pm0.08$ & $0.67\pm0.01$ & $48\pm3$ & $18^{+10}_{-17} $ & $33\pm4$ & $92\pm10$ &6.0/6142 \\
2685& $8.11\pm0.10$ & $0.66\pm0.01$ & $54\pm4$ & $0^{+14} $ & $38\pm6$ & $113\pm12$ &5.7/3256\\
3073& $11.11\pm0.12$ & $0.67\pm0.01$ & $34\pm5$ & $46\pm14$ & $40\pm3$ & $93\pm8$ &5.6/2662\\
3109& $9.7\pm0.1$ & $0.64\pm0.02$ & $18^{+10}_{-18} $ & $0^{+15} $ & $42\pm2$ & $88\pm7$ &17/1598 \\
3178& $11.71\pm0.09$ & $0.685\pm0.007$ & $45\pm2$ & $0^{+10} $ & $39\pm2$ & $103\pm7$ &4/3442\\
3436& $15.17\pm0.09$ & $0.705\pm0.005$ & $47\pm2$ & $24\pm11$ & $42\pm2$ & $95\pm4$ &4.9/4337\\
3485& $15.42\pm0.08$ & $0.707\pm0.005$ & $51\pm2$ & $1^{+10} $ & $43\pm2$ & $102\pm5$ &5.2/4702\\
3512& $15.43\pm0.12$ & $0.708\pm0.006$ & $53\pm2$ & $0^{+18} $ & $42\pm3$ & $94\pm6$ &3.3/2632\\
3914& $17.57\pm0.14$ & $0.694\pm0.007$ & $42\pm3$ & $0^{+10} $ & $38\pm3$ & $111\pm7$ &2.4/1272\\
4013& $19.09\pm0.10$ & $0.754\pm0.005$ & $46.4\pm1.4$ & $0^{+5} $ & $45.1\pm1.5$ & $104\pm4$ &3.0/2830\\
4016& $18.72\pm0.10$ & $0.745\pm0.006$ & $51\pm2$ & $0^{+5} $ & $46\pm2$ & $103\pm5$ &3.1/2512\\
4220& $20.20\pm0.09$ & $0.729\pm0.004$ & $43.4\pm1.3$ & $2^{+13}_{-2} $ & $37.6\pm1.3$ & $100\pm3$ &2.2/2955\\
4268& $21.78\pm0.13$ & $0.736\pm0.006$ & $40\pm2$ & $28\pm8$ & $38\pm2$ & $107\pm4$ &7.3/3862\\
4372& $22.94\pm0.10$ & $0.727\pm0.005$ & $37\pm2$ & $23\pm9$ & $37.4\pm1.5$ & $114\pm3$ &3.6/3532
\\
4577& $23.89\pm0.14$ & $0.757\pm0.007$ & $40\pm2$ & $21\pm6$ & $39\pm2$ & $103\pm4$ &7.0/3442\\
4584& $25.23\pm0.07$ & $0.747\pm0.003$ & $42.0\pm1.0$ & $0^{+5} $ & $38.5\pm1.0$ & $109\pm2$ &2.9/4222\\
4966& $29.45\pm0.06$ & $0.764\pm0.002$ & $40.8\pm0.6$ & $0^{+5} $ & $39.5\pm0.6$ & $108.3\pm1.3$ &1.3/50689\\
5011& $32.97\pm0.07$ & $0.775\pm0.002$ & $44.1\pm0.7$ & $1^{+5}_{-1} $ & $40.1\pm0.6$ & $104.9\pm1.4$ &1.4/50531\\
5387& $34.11\pm0.08$ & $0.790\pm0.003$ & $41.4\pm0.8$ & $0^{+3} $ & $41.5\pm0.7$ & $107.8\pm1.5$ &1.6/39604\\
5748& $41.68\pm0.07$ & $0.811\pm0.002$ & $43.8\pm0.5$ & $0^{+2} $ & $40.2\pm0.5$ & $103.1\pm1.2$ &1.3/38992\\
5810& $42.46\pm0.07$ & $0.815\pm0.002$ & $42.9\pm0.5$ & $1^{+4}_{-1} $ & $42.8\pm0.6$ & $117.4\pm1.0$ &1.6/46012\\
6003& $46.50\pm0.07$ & $0.815\pm0.002$ & $39.6\pm0.5$ & $0^{+2} $ & $38.4\pm0.5$ & $101.2\pm1.1$ &1.6/44992\\
6129& $52.82\pm0.08$ & $0.833\pm0.002$ & $42.7\pm0.5$ & $0^{+2} $ & $42.1\pm0.4$ & $107.7\pm1.1$ &1.3/46012\\
6170& $54.05\pm0.08$ & $0.831\pm0.002$ & $42.2\pm0.5$ & $0^{+2} $ & $38.8\pm0.4$ & $107.8\pm1.1$ &1.5/43672\\
6283& $53.63\pm0.07$ & $0.829\pm0.001$ & $39.6\pm0.4$ & $0^{+2} $ & $38.8\pm0.4$ & $107.7\pm0.9$ &1.5/44842\\
6605& $61.36\pm0.10$ & $0.843\pm0.002$ & $38.2\pm0.5$ & $0^{+2} $ & $39.1\pm0.5$ & $109.0\pm1.1$ &2.9/42892\\
6693& $62.69\pm0.08$ & $0.858\pm0.001$ & $43.0\pm0.4$ & $0^{+3} $ & $35.9\pm0.4$ & $101.5\pm1.0$ &1.5/38992\\
6973& $73.81\pm0.08$ & $0.880\pm0.001$ & $44.6\pm0.3$ & $0^{+2} $ & $42.1\pm0.4$ & $117.4\pm0.7$ &1.5/40357\\
7085& $77.19\pm0.08$ & $0.872\pm0.001$ & $39.3\pm0.3$ & $0^{+1} $ & $39.8\pm0.3$ & $111.8\pm0.6$ &1.5/29112\\
7228& $82.51\pm0.08$ & $0.874\pm0.001$ & $40.0\pm0.3$ & $0^{+1} $ & $39.4\pm0.3$ & $109.1\pm0.7$ &1.4/35677\\
7620& $93.61\pm0.09$ & $0.893\pm0.001$ & $42.7\pm0.3$ & $0^{+4} $ & $38.9\pm0.3$ & $105.1\pm0.6$ &1.3/42892\\
7730& $98.98\pm0.08$ & $0.8905\pm0.0008$ & $36.2\pm0.2$ & $0^{+1} $ & $36.3\pm0.2$ & $109.4\pm0.5$ &1.6/40942\\
7901& $107.73\pm0.08$ & $0.8916\pm0.0007$ & $35.8\pm0.2$ & $0^{+2} $ & $35.9\pm0.2$ & $109.1\pm0.4$ &1.5/44452\\
8139& $121.59\pm0.08$ & $0.9095\pm0.0006$ & $37.6\pm0.1$ & $0^{+4} $ & $32.0\pm0.1$ & $104.4\pm0.4$ &0.5/278820\\
8370& $128.07\pm0.08$ & $0.9142\pm0.0006$ & $36.6\pm0.2$ & $0^{+1} $ & $33.4\pm0.2$ & $105.4\pm0.4$ &0.8/254302\\
8448& $132.59\pm0.07$ & $0.9109\pm0.0008$ & $33.5\pm0.2$ & $12\pm3$ & $28.7\pm0.1$ & $103.4\pm0.4$ &0.9/301177\\
8737& $142.25\pm0.07$ & $0.9185\pm0.0005$ & $32.8\pm0.1$ & $0^{+2} $ & $29.8\pm0.1$ & $104.2\pm0.4$ &0.6/251707\\
8824& $136.58\pm0.08$ & $0.9169\pm0.0008$ & $28.4\pm0.2$ & $1^{+3}_{-1} $ & $26.9\pm0.1$ & $105.7\pm0.4$ &0.7/241327\\
9089& $155.92\pm0.06$ & $0.9251\pm0.0005$ & $30.5\pm0.1$ & $0^{+1} $ & $25.8\pm0.1$ & $102.3\pm0.4$ &1.1/265987\\
9233& $161.00\pm0.06$ & $0.9290\pm0.0006$ & $28.8\pm0.1$ & $1^{+2}_{-1} $ & $25.8\pm0.1$ & $102.4\pm0.3$ &1.0/301177\\
9321& $165.62\pm0.05$ & $0.9304\pm0.0003$ & $29.1\pm0.1$ & $0^{+1} $ & $23.5\pm0.1$ & $98.4\pm0.3$ &0.9/284272\\
9509& $168.68\pm0.05$ & $0.9467\pm0.0003$ & $31.7\pm0.1$ & $0^{+1} $ & $26.7\pm0.1$ & $97.8\pm0.2$ &1.4/288550\\
9568& $176.01\pm0.04$ & $0.9378\pm0.0002$ & $28.6\pm0.1$ & $0^{+1} $ & $18.4\pm0.1$ & $111.6\pm0.3$ &1.3/283341 \\
        \hline
        9,642 & 175.81 $\pm$ 0.04 & 0.9464 $\pm$ 0.0002 & 29.68 $\pm$ 0.05 & 0 $\pm$ 1 & 21.30 $\pm$ 0.04 & 99.6 $\pm$ .2 & 0.693/ 234782 \\
        9,756 & 179.87 $\pm$ 0.04 & 0.9508 $\pm$ 0.0002 & 30.84 $\pm$ 0.06 & 0 $\pm$ 1 & 21.98 $\pm$ 0.05 & 103.5 $\pm$ 0.2 & 0.764/ 233190 \\
        9,915 & 185.96 $\pm$ 0.0005 & 0.9583 $\pm$ 0.0003 & 30.55 $\pm$ 0.06 & 0 $\pm$ 2 & 20.57 $\pm$ 5 & 94.7 $\pm$ 0.3 & 0.7947/230290 \\
        10,601 & 199.45$\pm$ .06 & 0.9857 $\pm$ .0003& 32.48 $\pm$ 0.07 & 0 $\pm$ 7 & 15.42 $\pm$ 0.5 & 88.6 $\pm$ 0.4 &0.578/118446 \\
        10,942 & 216.43 $\pm$ 0.06 & 0.9975 $\pm$ 0.0002 & 28.36 $\pm$ 0.05 & 9 $\pm$ 8 & 10.36 $\pm$ 6 & 87.5 $\pm$ 0.5 &  0.546/190019 \\
\enddata
\tablenotetext{a}{Before 2000, all 26 frequency channels in the data were
averaged into one band of effective bandwidth 208\,MHz to boost the signal;
between 2000 and 2009, 26 Hanning-smoothed channels, each of width 8\,MHz were
used in the fit; since mid-2009, after the installation of the Compact Array
Broadband Backend (CABB), 208 channels in the same frequency range were extracted,
each of width 1\,MHz. Since 2012, the ATCA sensitivity has improved by
$\sim$40\% as a result of the installation of new receivers.}
\label{table:torus}
\end{deluxetable*}

\cleardoublepage

\startlongtable
\begin{deluxetable*}{lccccccr}
\tablecaption{Best-fit Parameters for the Ring Model with Statistical
Uncertainties at 68\% Confidence Level\label{table:ring}}
\ref{table:ring}
\centering
\tablewidth{\textwidth}
\tabletypesize{\small}
\tablehead{
\colhead{Day}&\colhead{Flux (mJy)}&\colhead{Semi-major}&
\colhead{Semi-minor}&\colhead{Asymmetry}&\colhead{$\phi$
(\arcdeg)}&\colhead{$\chi^2_\nu$/dof\tablenotemark{a}}\\
&&\colhead{Axis (\arcsec)}&\colhead{Axis (\arcsec)}&
\colhead{(\%)} &}
\startdata
1786& $3.70\pm0.12$ & $0.55\pm0.03$ & $0.50\pm0.03$ & $33\pm16$ & $141\pm26$ &1.8/2108\\
1852& $3.59\pm0.14$ & $0.53\pm0.04$ & $0.48\pm0.04$ & $25\pm17$ & $124\pm46$ &3.7/1643\\
2067& $5.17\pm0.09$ & $0.57\pm0.02$ & $0.49\pm0.01$ & $27\pm5$ & $105\pm16$ &4.4/3603\\
2142& $4.84\pm0.11$ & $0.53\pm0.02$ & $0.51\pm0.02$ & $17\pm8$ & $132\pm29$ &17/2703\\
2143& $5.62\pm0.14$ & $0.63\pm0.03$ & $0.44\pm0.02$ & $39\pm8$ & $94\pm24$ &16/1393\\
2313& $6.68\pm0.09$ & $0.57\pm0.02$ & $0.44\pm0.01$ & $34\pm5$ & $90\pm15$ &3.6/2903\\
2320& $6.87\pm0.10$ & $0.61\pm0.02$ & $0.47\pm0.01$ & $31\pm4$ & $92\pm13$ &4.5/2963\\
2426& $6.47\pm0.08$ & $0.56\pm0.01$ & $0.50\pm0.01$ & $28\pm4$ & $86\pm9$ &5.2/4373\\
2550& $6.12\pm0.12$ & $0.58\pm0.02$ & $0.54\pm0.02$ & $32\pm6$ & $117\pm12$ &7.5/2993\\
2681& $8.23\pm0.06$ & $0.58\pm0.01$ & $0.48\pm0.01$ & $26\pm3$ & $87\pm8$ &6.0/6143\\
2685& $7.94\pm0.08$ & $0.56\pm0.01$ & $0.49\pm0.01$ & $29\pm4$ & $109\pm10$ &5.7/3257\\
3073& $10.86\pm0.10$ & $0.62\pm0.01$ & $0.47\pm0.01$ & $33\pm2$ & $87\pm8$ &5.6/2663\\
3109& $9.73\pm0.23$ & $0.60\pm0.01$ & $0.50\pm0.01$ & $36\pm8$ & $92\pm32$ &17/1599\\
3178& $11.50\pm0.07$ & $0.601\pm0.007$ & $0.487\pm0.006$ & $32\pm2$ & $98\pm6$ &4.0/3443\\
3436& $14.76\pm0.07$ & $0.607\pm0.005$ & $0.495\pm0.004$ & $33\pm1$ & $94\pm4$ &5.0/4338\\
3485& $15.07\pm0.07$ & $0.598\pm0.006$ & $0.510\pm0.004$ & $33\pm2$ & $98\pm4$ &5.2/4703\\
3512& $15.06\pm0.10$ & $0.592\pm0.007$ & $0.508\pm0.005$ & $32\pm2$ & $91\pm5$ &3.4/2633\\
3914& $17.31\pm0.12$ & $0.624\pm0.006$ & $0.491\pm0.007$ & $33\pm3$ & $107\pm7$ &2.4/1273\\
4013& $18.53\pm0.09$ & $0.646\pm0.005$ & $0.527\pm0.004$ & $35.5\pm1.2$ & $99\pm3$ &3.0/2831\\
4016& $18.36\pm0.09$ & $0.632\pm0.005$ & $0.545\pm0.006$ & $35.8\pm1.3$ & $98\pm4$ &3.1/2513\\
4220& $19.76\pm0.07$ & $0.643\pm0.004$ & $0.509\pm0.003$ & $31.4\pm1.0$ & $96\pm3$ &2.2/2956\\
4268& $21.19\pm0.11$ & $0.656\pm0.006$ & $0.506\pm0.005$ & $31.1\pm1.5$ & $104\pm4$ &7.4/3863\\
4372& $22.43\pm0.08$ & $0.663\pm0.004$ & $0.500\pm0.004$ & $32.1\pm1.2$ & $111\pm3$ &3.6/3533\\
4577& $23.26\pm0.12$ & $0.674\pm0.006$ & $0.515\pm0.005$ & $32.7\pm1.4$ & $98\pm4$ &7.1/3443\\
4584& $24.69\pm0.07$ & $0.663\pm0.003$ & $0.521\pm0.003$ & $31.6\pm0.8$ & $103\pm2$ &2.9/4223\\
4966& $28.75\pm0.05$ & $0.681\pm0.002$ & $0.527\pm0.002$ & $32.9\pm0.5$ & $102\pm1$ &1.3/50690\\
5011& $32.03\pm0.06$ & $0.677\pm0.002$ & $0.531\pm0.002$ & $32.7\pm0.5$ & $100\pm1$ &1.4/50532\\
5387& $33.19\pm0.07$ & $0.694\pm0.002$ & $0.547\pm0.002$ & $34.0\pm0.5$ & $102\pm1$ &1.6/39605\\
5748& $40.56\pm0.06$ & $0.710\pm0.002$ & $0.564\pm0.001$ & $33.0\pm0.4$ & $97\pm1$ &1.3/38993\\
5810& $41.24\pm0.06$ & $0.723\pm0.002$ & $0.568\pm0.002$ & $34.8\pm0.4$ & $110\pm1$ &1.6/46013\\
6003& $45.35\pm0.06$ & $0.723\pm0.002$ & $0.561\pm0.002$ & $32.2\pm0.4$ & $94\pm1$ &1.6/44993\\
6129& $51.43\pm0.07$ & $0.733\pm0.002$ & $0.579\pm0.002$ & $34.7\pm0.3$ & $100\pm1$ &1.3/46013\\
6170& $52.63\pm0.07$ & $0.734\pm0.001$ & $0.577\pm0.002$ & $32.1\pm0.3$ & $102\pm1$ &1.5/43673\\
6283& $52.18\pm0.06$ & $0.743\pm0.001$ & $0.569\pm0.001$ & $32.8\pm0.3$ & $101\pm1$ &1.5/44843\\
6605& $59.86\pm0.09$ & $0.758\pm0.002$ & $0.586\pm0.002$ & $33.0\pm0.4$ & $101\pm1$ &2.9/42893\\
6693& $61.21\pm0.07$ & $0.7622\pm0.0013$ & $0.5979\pm0.0013$ & $30.1\pm0.3$ & $95\pm1$ &1.5/38993\\
6973& $71.33\pm0.07$ & $0.7743\pm0.0011$ & $0.6118\pm0.0014$ & $33.7\pm0.3$ & $110\pm1$ &1.5/40358\\
7085& $74.60\pm0.07$ & $0.7695\pm0.0012$ & $0.5939\pm0.0011$ & $32.6\pm0.2$ & $103\pm1$ &1.6/29113\\
7228& $80.53\pm0.07$ & $0.7825\pm0.0009$ & $0.6171\pm0.0010$ & $33.0\pm0.2$ & $101\pm1$ &1.4/35678\\
7620& $90.47\pm0.08$ & $0.7830\pm0.0011$ & $0.6208\pm0.0009$ & $31.8\pm0.2$ & $97\pm1$ &1.4/42893\\
7730& $96.36\pm0.07$ & $0.8058\pm0.0008$ & $0.6179\pm0.0008$ & $30.9\pm0.2$ & $102\pm1$ &1.6/40943\\
7901& $104.94\pm0.06$ & $0.8075\pm0.0007$ & $0.6220\pm0.0007$ & $30.8\pm0.1$ & $102\pm0$ &1.5/44453\\
8139& $117.73\pm0.07$ & $0.8241\pm0.0006$ & $0.6263\pm0.0006$ & $27.7\pm0.1$ & $97\pm0$ &0.5/278821 \\
8370& $124.86\pm0.07$ & $0.8243\pm0.0006$ & $0.6428\pm0.0007$ & $28.6\pm0.1$ & $98\pm0$ &0.8/254303 \\
8448& $129.50\pm0.06$ & $0.8406\pm0.0005$ & $0.6282\pm0.0006$ & $25.6\pm0.1$ & $94\pm0$ &0.9/301178 \\
8737& $139.17\pm0.06$ & $0.8433\pm0.0005$ & $0.6430\pm0.0005$ & $26.2\pm0.1$ & $96\pm0$ &0.7/251708 \\
8824& $133.95\pm0.07$ & $0.8582\pm0.0006$ & $0.6373\pm0.0007$ & $24.1\pm0.1$ & $96\pm0$ &0.7/241328 \\
9089& $153.09\pm0.05$ & $0.8593\pm0.0004$ & $0.6438\pm0.0005$ & $23.1\pm0.1$ & $92\pm0$ &1.1/265988 \\
9233& $157.94\pm0.05$ & $0.8698\pm0.0004$ & $0.6401\pm0.0005$ & $23.4\pm0.1$ & $93\pm0$ &1.1/301178 \\
9321& $162.98\pm0.05$ & $0.8703\pm0.0003$ & $0.6527\pm0.0004$ & $21.5\pm0.1$ & $88\pm0$ &0.9/284273 \\
9509& $165.10\pm0.04$ & $0.8761\pm0.0003$ & $0.6583\pm0.0003$ & $24.0\pm0.1$ & $88\pm0$ &1.4/288551 \\
9568& $173.03\pm0.04$ & $0.8818\pm0.0002$ & $0.6574\pm0.0003$ & $16.2\pm0.1$ & $100\pm0$ &1.4/283342 \\
\hline
9,642 & 171.54$\pm$ .04 & 0.878 $\pm$ 0.0002 & 0.658 $\pm$ 0.0002 & 19.28 $\pm$ 0.04 & 81.7 $\pm$ 0.2 &0.762/258312 \\
9,756 & 176.54$\pm$ .04 & 0.881 $\pm$ 0.0002 & 0.669 $\pm$ 0.0003 & 19.53 $\pm$ 0.04 & 93.1 $\pm$ 0.1 &0.837/4255481 \\
9,915 & 181.69 $\pm$ .05 & 0.891 $\pm$ 0.0003 & 0.663 $\pm$ 0.0003 & 18.87 $\pm$ 0.05 & 89.1 $\pm$ 0.3 &0.655/152784 \\
10,601 & 195.68$\pm$ .06 & 0.918 $\pm$ 0.0003 & 0.691 $\pm$ 0.0003 & 14.61 $\pm$ 0.06 & 74.1 $\pm$ 0.4 &0.651/133454 \\
10,942 & 209.78 $\pm$ .06 & 0.934 $\pm$ 0.0003 & 0.634 $\pm$ 0.0003 & 10.64 $\pm$ 0.07 & 64.1 $\pm$ 0.4 & 0.653/227191 \\
\enddata 
\tablenotetext{a}{Before 2000, all 26 frequency channels in the data were
averaged into one band of effective bandwidth 208\,MHz to boost the signal;
between 2000 and 2009, 26 Hanning-smoothed channels, each of width 8\,MHz were
used in the fit; since mid-2009, after the installation of the Compact Array
Broadband Backend (CABB), 208 channels in the same frequency range were extracted,
each of width 1\,MHz. Since 2012, the ATCA sensitivity has improved by
$\sim$40\% as a result of the installation of new receivers.}
\end{deluxetable*}

\end{document}
```

Class `aastex61` comes from this [journal](http://journals.aas.org/authors/aastex/aasguide.html).

Comment: @kb3hts was the original question [this one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/398376/long-table-cutting-off-before-end-of-table)?

Comment: not sure which packages are involved (and at fault) here - but it seems the problem is gone if any content appears after the table. i.e., any text or even an empty inline math `\(\)` makes the table appear in full.

Answer (score 2):

Without being sure what causes the problem or which package(s) is(are) at fault, the problem seems to vanish if any content appears after the table.

Thus, to circumvent the problem, one might, e.g., place an empty inline math (`\(\)`) after the table and the table should print in full.